# Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server or _session or globals passed to script

Tags: php, joomla

In my website when I am clicking on "career"tab then this error is coming
On "career" I have provided the link of a sub-domain(http://career.codescape.in)

When I google it and searched it on stackflow I have found the solutions like

- Instead of numeric ,give alphabetic names of fields in form
- Change    global settings of error reporting in Joomla
- Upgrade Joomla version

I have tried the above suggestions bur still my error is coming.Anyone plz tell me why this error occurs and how can I rectify it asap.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please specify a URL or URLs that cause the trouble. Link to live example is preferred. What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://codescape.in 
In this site the career link causes problem

Comment: It is due to a numeric or other "banned" key, which could be produced by your server before the script is handed over to the PHP interpreter. This test was removed in later versions of Joomla!. You can override it in code, or identify its cause (the relevant file: `libraries/joomla/environment/request.php`).

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions you quoted? Why can't you do any of those suggested solutions, and what other possible answers did you expect to be given?

Comment: @MasterAM When I have downloaded Joomla_3.15 then there is no file request.php in libraries/joomla/enviornment

Comment: That's what I meant. This was removed somewhere between 1.5 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen due to saving wrong data on browser cookie.

Check what information are storing in browser cookie while rendering this page.

Tips:

1 Clear Browser cookie load again.

2 Open the page in different browser.

Check what wrong with your cookie saving section.

Hope it will helps..

Comment: I am new so dont know this much how to do it.Kindly help
On the webpage career.codescape.in I inspect element the page and see the cookies values in resouces but did not understand it.
I have cleared browser cookies and opened in another browser also but no result.

Comment: this may be The cookie issue happen at joomla frame work loading time. did you check any other page available on this joomla installtion. Also please check what file modified last. Bcoz  its happen on framework loading so page view source will not gets.

Comment: I dont know perfectly how to deal with Joomla files.
This site has been made before by someone and its been assigned to me to resolve the error.
Kindly suggest me in which file or where I have to change the cookie settings.

Comment: Ok, If this is the case then you have to check like .debug step by step. Joomla rendering starts from framework.php inside includes/ before including each file just give echo "1" ,echo "2" etc. Then check  which step create issue .Also if it pass fine then starts from your template. like templates/your_tempname/index.php. before trying this you must have to clear cookie.

Comment: In Framework.php its written in first line 
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

and it displays Restricted access